# Computing the order of a divisor in the Jacobian of a hyperelliptic curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves, cryptography

Given a hyperelliptic curve of genus $g$, of equation $H: y^{2}+h(x)y=f(x)$ and defined over the finite field $\mathbb{K}$, how does one compute the order of a (reduced) divisor defined over $\mathbb{K}$ in the jacobian of the curve?

Since for every reduced divisor we have the corresponding Mumford representation (U(x),V(x)), I would say that one only needs to look at the addition using Cantor's algorithm. Is there an algorithmic approach to computing it rapidly?

(A point to a reference material would also be greatly appreciated).